# Rename All Files in Folder with Added Variable Value without Opening

Tags: vba

I have a large number of *.xlsx files in subfolders based on month of the year (e.g., 01, 02, 03) by district.  I'd like to loop through each file and append the period associated with the subfolder to the end of each file name.  For example, **Atlanta 01 Bob Jones.xlsx** would become **Atlanta 01 Bob Jones 01.xlsx**.  I have looked at examples on this forum and elsewhere and can't find something similar enough to do what I want.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub DSMReports1()
Dim MM As String
MM = InputBox("Enter Month for reporting in MM format: 01-12", , Range("C6").Value)
Range("C6").Value = MM
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim DistrictDSM As String
Dim Path As String
Dim DistPeriodFileOld As String
Dim DistPeriodFileNew As String
Dim Total As Integer
Dim Period As Integer

    DistrictDSM = Range("B3").Value 'Selected from a dropdown list

    Path = "H:\Accounting\Monthend 2018\DSM Files\" & DistrictDSM & "\P" & MM & "\"
    DistPeriodFileOld = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    DistPeriodFileNew = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx") 'This is where I'd like to append the period value found in MM

    Do While DistPeriodFileOld <> ""
       Name DistPeriodFileOld As DistPeriodFileNew

       DistPeriodFileOld = Dir

    Loop

    Next DistrictDSM

    End Sub
```

Comment: You can just replace the .xlsx with #.xlsx?  in this line `DistPeriodFileNew = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx") `

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work properly.  I don't want to replace the name of the file with a number, but want to rename the file so that the period is appended (either as 01 or P01) to the existing file name.

Comment: As shown in the example above, I would want **Atlanta 01 Bob Jones.xlsx** to be renamed **Atlanta 01 Bob Jones 01.xlsx** (or **Atlanta 01 Bob Jones P01.xlsx**).   So in this example for the first period (i.e., 01 = January), if there are six files in this folder--Atlanta 01 Bob Jones.xlsx to Atlanta 06 Bob Jones.xlsx--each would be renamed with either the 01 or P01 to correspond with the period shown in the folder name, with the resulting files named from Atlanta 01 Bob Jones 01.xlsx to Atlanta 06 Bob Jones 01.xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of *.xlsx, I believe that this code can help you.

```
Sub ReadAllFiles(ByVal s As String)
    'Remember: Add Reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime
        Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
        Dim myFolder As Folder
        Dim myFile As File
        Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(s)
        For Each myFile In myFolder.Files
                If UCase(Mid$(myFile.Name, Len(myFile.Name) - 3, 4)) = ".XLS" Or UCase(Mid$(myFile.Name, Len(myFile.Name) - 3, 4)) = "XLSX" Then
                     Debug.Print "readind file " & myFile.Path
                End If
        Next
End Sub
```

After, you need to replace old name to new name.

```
Function RenameFiles(p_file As String) As String
'Atlanta 01 Bob Jones.xlsx
Dim v_name As String
Dim v_extension As String
If UCase(Mid$(p_file, Len(p_file) - 3, 4)) = ".XLS" Then
   v_name = Mid$(p_file, 1, Len(p_file) - 4) 'Atlanta 01 Bob Jones
   v_extension = Mid$(p_file, Len(p_file) - 2, 4) '.xls
End If
If UCase(Mid$(p_file, Len(p_file) - 3, 4)) = "XLSX" Then
   v_name = Mid$(p_file, 1, Len(p_file) - 5) 'Atlanta 01 Bob Jones
   v_extension = Mid$(p_file, Len(p_file) - 3, 4) '.xls
End If
RenameFiles = v_name & " 01" & "." & v_extension 'warning --> I fixed 01 here
End Function
```

Finally:

```
Sub ReadAllFiles(ByVal s As String)
'Remember: Add Reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Dim myFile As File
    Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(s)
    For Each myFile In myFolder.Files
            If UCase(Mid$(myFile.Name, Len(myFile.Name) - 3, 4)) = ".XLS" Or UCase(Mid$(myFile.Name, Len(myFile.Name) - 3, 4)) = "XLSX" Then
                 Debug.Print "reading file " & myFile.Path
                 FileCopy myFile.Path, RenameFiles(myFile.Path) 'Here we COPY original file to new file
            End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I hope I have helped you.

Comment: To test ==> execute ===> ReadAllFiles("H:\some_directory\")

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and for getting back to me so quickly!  However, I want to limit the replacement to a specific subfolder at a time. It appears from the above code that this would go through every folder and subfolder at once, which is not appropriate to what I need. Can you suggest a way of limiting the folder that is opened in the Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(s) code?

Comment: This code is not recursive. If you set the destination folder "H:\some_directory\", the code will no be able to read the subfolders "H:\some_directory\2018\Jan" or "H:\some_directory\2018\Feb". If you want a code that does it, I'll send other to you.